# What exactly is Pratt parsing used for and how does it work?

Tags: parsing

I've come across the term “Pratt parsing”. The only thing I know is that it's an algorithm (or a pattern, a technique) used to parse expressions.

How does it work? I'd like to see the intuition behind the algorithm, not just a series of steps to perform. What problems does this technique actually solve, and at what cost? How is it different from other well-known traditional/basic parsing strategies? Has it been “superseded” (at least in some aspects) by better techniques?

Comment: A discussion you might find interesting: https://www.reddit.com/r/ProgrammingLanguages/comments/16vqbey/alternatives_to_the_shunting_yard_algorithm_for/?rdt=56610

Comment: I'm surprised this hadn't already been asked!

Comment: also: https://journal.stuffwithstuff.com/2011/03/19/pratt-parsers-expression-parsing-made-easy/

Comment: also: https://matklad.github.io/2020/04/13/simple-but-powerful-pratt-parsing.html

Answer (score 8, accepted):

### Motivation

> What problems does this technique actually solve, and at what cost?

In a BNF grammar, you need a nonterminal for each level of operator precedence.

⟨*additive*⟩ =
  ⟨*multiplicative*⟩ ( (`+` | `-`) ⟨*multiplicative*⟩ )*

⟨*multiplicative*⟩ =
  ⟨*unary*⟩ ( (`*` | `/`) ⟨*unary*⟩ )*

⟨*unary*⟩ =
  (`+` | `-`) ⟨*term*⟩

⟨*term*⟩ =
  ⟨*number*⟩ | ⟨*variable*⟩

If you translate this to a recursive-descent parser, each nonterminal becomes a function. In pseudo-Python:

```
def accept_additive():
    lhs = accept_multiplicative()
    if lhs is None:
        return None

    while True:
        op = accept_additive_operator()
        if op is None:
            break
        rhs = expect_multiplicative()
        lhs = Binary(op, lhs, rhs)

    return lhs

def accept_additive_operator():
    return accept_token('+') or accept_token('-')

def expect_multiplicative():
    e = accept_multiplicative()
    if e is None:
        raise ParseError()
    return e

def accept_multiplicative():
    ...

def accept_multiplicative_operator():
    ...

def expect_unary():
    ...

def accept_unary():
    ...

def accept_unary_operator():
    ...

def expect_term():
    ...

def accept_term():
    return accept_number() or accept_variable()
```

So it takes many nested calls to reach the parsers for the leaves of the AST: before the parser even consumes a character, it must go down the chain of `accept_additive()` → `accept_multiplicative()` → `accept_unary()` → `accept_term()`, most of which is unproductive.

### Solution

> How does it work?

> How is it different from other well-known traditional/basic parsing strategies?

In [Top-Down Operator Precedence Parsing](https://dl.acm.org/doi/10.1145/512927.512931), Vaughan Pratt devised a method of simplifying this pattern, in a way that integrates well with recursive descent parsing.

The technique is to add a precedence table, which associates each operator token with a few properties:

- “Left binding power” (LBP), an integer precedence level
- “Null denotation” (NUD), a function to parse it in prefix position (nothing to its left)
- “Left denotation” (LED), a function to parse it in infix position (something to its left)

The chain of calls is replaced by a single loop that uses the token to dispatch to the appropriate parser immediately, skipping over the irrelevant precedence levels. In this case, the precedence levels are these.

0. Literal / Minimum
1. Additive
2. Multiplicative / Maximum

So the table looks like this. Notice that there’s an extra “end” marker token with minimum precedence.

| Token | Precedence (LBP) | Prefix (NUD) | Infix (LED) |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| `*` | Multiplicative (2) | `None` | `mul_led` |
| `/` | Multiplicative (2) | `None` | `div_led` |
| `+` | Additive (1) | `add_nud` | `add_led` |
| `-` | Additive (1) | `sub_nud` | `sub_led` |
| Number | Literal (0) | `num_nud` | `None` |
| Variable | Literal (0) | `var_nud` | `None` |
| End | Minimum (0) | `None` | `None` |

`None` indicates cases where a parse error could occur, so this also allows context-sensitive error reporting.

The top-level expression parser can now work iteratively. It’s parameterised by a “*right* binding power” (RBP), which starts at the minimum precedence level when parsing a top-level expression. It grabs a token and tries to parse it as a prefix operator, then repeatedly tries to parse infix expressions above the current precedence level.

```
def accept_expression(rbp):
    current = next_token()
    lhs = table[current].nud()
    while table[current].lbp > rbp:
        operator = current
        current = next_token()
        lhs = table[operator].led(lhs)
    return lhs
```

This is the sense in which it’s “top-down”: like the recursive descent parser, it considers the lowest-precedence operators first, and makes recursive calls at higher precedence levels. The definitions of the individual operator parsers, where this recursion actually happens, are quite mechanical:

```
def add_nud():
    return expect_expression(PREC_MAX)

def add_led(lhs):
    return Binary('+', lhs, expect_expression(PREC_ADD))
```

A right-associative operator would use a lower precedence than the current level; for example, take exponentiation:

```
def exp_led(lhs):
    return Binary('^', lhs, expect_expression(PREC_EXP - 1))
```

### Conclusion

> Has it been “superseded” (at least in some aspects) by better techniques?

Mostly it hasn’t. Parser generators like [Happy](https://monlih.github.io/happy-docs/) and parser combinator libraries like [Megaparsec](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/megaparsec) do have some facilities for handling operator precedence automatically. However, you may still need to write a recursive descent parser by hand in order to gracefully recover from errors and produce helpful feedback. In that case, Pratt parsing is a nice technique for simplifying the parser and improving its performance compared to naïve RD. It readily admits user-defined operators, by just allowing the precedence table to be extended, and it works equally well in imperative and functional style.

Finally, operator-precedence grammars can describe a fairly large class of languages, too, so it’s also quite possible to parse a language *entirely* with this technique, or only modest extensions. For example, I once wrote a language where `if` was considered a prefix binary operator and `else` an infix binary operator, with precedence and associativity defined so that `if A B else if C D else E` would parse as `(if A B) else ((if C D) else E)`.

Comment: There is currently an effort in the Ruby community to replace the aging "Flex/Bison-with-lots-of-hand-written-code" parser of YARV, which due to Ruby's complex syntax also ended up being used by every other Ruby implementation (despite the fact it is not designed for re-use and intimately tied to YARV), with a new parser that is designed for re-use, has no dependencies on YARV, and can be used by all other Ruby implementations as well as refactoring tools, IDEs, linters, syntax highlighters, etc. It is called Prism and is a hand-written Pratt-style TDOP parser: https://github.com/ruby/prism/